# Android java: OnTouchListener return false but keep handling subsequent actions

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener

I am making an app for Android in java and have a problem on with the `OnTouch`:

I want to return false after handling the `ACTION_MOVE` event to have a sub view also handle the event, but still keep track of the following `ACTION_MOVE` and `ACTION_UP` events with the first handler.

Which is deactivated by the `return false` as said on the Android Developer wbesite:

> onTouch() - This returns a boolean to indicate whether your listener
>   consumes this event. The important thing is that this event can have
>   multiple actions that follow each other. So, if you return false when
>   the down action event is received, you indicate that you have not
>   consumed the event and are also not interested in subsequent actions
>   from this event. Thus, you will not be called for any other actions
>   within the event, such as a finger gesture, or the eventual up action
>   event.

is there a way to not have that?

Comment: Have you tried sending the onTouch manually to the subviews?

Comment: i tried to use the dispatch on the groupview holding the subview, but it apparently sends the event to all the subviews and not the one who has the move in the right bounds...

PS: it is a chess bord, with a piece that i am moving over the board and i want to save the cell currently under the piece with its own move handler, but still keep moving the piece after that ofc...

Comment: What if you just return `super.onTouch()`?